# The property 'DepartmentID' cannot be configured as a navigation property

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, code-first, foreign-key-relationship

**Designation Class**

```
public class Designation
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    [Key]
    public int  id  { get; set; }

     [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    [ForeignKey("DepartmentID")]
    public int DepartmentID { get; set; }



    public bool IsActive { get; set; }

    public string AddedBy { get; set; }

    public DateTime AddedDate { get; set; }
    public string UpdateBy { get; set; }

    public DateTime UpdateDate { get; set; }
    public virtual  Department Department { get; set; }
}
```

**Department Class**

```
public class Department
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    [Key]
    public int DepartmentID { get; set; }
    public string DepartmentName { get; set; }

    public bool IsActive { get; set; }

    public string AddedBy { get; set; }

    public DateTime AddedDate { get; set; }
    public string UpdateBy { get; set; }

    public DateTime UpdateDate { get; set; }
    public virtual  ICollection<Designation> Designations { get; set; }
}
```

**EmployeeInfo Class**

```
public class EmployeeInfo
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    [Key]
    public int EmployeeID { get; set; }
    public int DepartmentID { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("DepartmentID")]
    public virtual Department Department { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Employee Name is Required"), Display(Name = "Name")]
    public string EmployeeName { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Employee Bangla Name is Required"), Display(Name = "Bangla Name")]
    public string EmployeeBanglaName { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Department Name is Required")]
    public string Department { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Designation is Required")]
    public string Designation { get; set; }
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public DateTime JoiningDate{ get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "BloodGroup is Required"), Display(Name = "Blood Group")]
    public string BloodGroup { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Gender is Required")]      
    public gender Gender { get; set; }   
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Father Name is Required"), Display(Name = "Father Name")]
    public string FatherName { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Mother Name is Required"), Display(Name = "Mother Name")]
    public string MotherName { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Husband/Wife Name is Required"), Display(Name = "Spouse Name")]
    public string SpouseName { get; set; }
    public string ChildrenNumber { get; set; }
    public string CardNumber { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Contact No is Required"), DataType(DataType.PhoneNumber)]
    public string ContactNo { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Email is Required"), DataType(DataType.EmailAddress), StringLength(200)]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "HomeContactNo is Required"),DataType(DataType.PhoneNumber)]
    public string HomeContactNo { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "District Name is Required")]
    public string District { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Thana is Required")]
    public string Thana { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Village Name is Required")]
    public string Vill { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Post Code is Required")]
    public string PostCode { get; set; }
    public string Image { get; set; }
    public byte[] picture { get; set; }
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }

    public string AddedBy { get; set; }

    public DateTime AddedDate { get; set; }
    public string UpdateBy { get; set; }

    public DateTime UpdateDate { get; set; }
}
```

**gender Enum**

```
public enum gender
{
    Male,
    Female,enter code here
    Other
}
```

Comment: i want to make foreign key relationship with three models/ tables by departmentID  but error shows like this>The property 'DepartmentID' cannot be configured as a navigation property. The property must be a valid entity type and the property should have a non-abstract getter and setter. For collection properties the type must implement ICollection<T> where T is a valid entity type

my model is

Comment: YOu should not be writing your question in Comment. Please try to edit your question and write your details there

Comment: Remove `[ForeignKey("DepartmentID")]` from `public int DepartmentID { get; set; }` (if its needed, it would need to be applied to the `public virtual  Department Department { get; set; }` property (but its not in your case). You also need to remove `[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]` from it as well.

Answer (score 1):

Use `[ForeignKey("DepartmentID")]` on your `public virtual  Department Department { get; set; }` property rather than `DepartmentID` property. Thus `DepartmentID` would be identified as a foreign key for Associated `Department`.

Even you dont need to set the ForeignKey Attribute as you have set the `DepartmentID` name as same as Department associated object property, by default convention EF sets `DepartmentID` as a foreign key.

See bellow code, you will have a clear picture.

```
public class Designation
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    [Key]
    public int  id  { get; set; }

    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]

    public int DepartmentID { get; set; }

    public bool IsActive { get; set; }

    public string AddedBy { get; set; }

    public DateTime AddedDate { get; set; }
    public string UpdateBy { get; set; }

    public DateTime UpdateDate { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("DepartmentID")]
    public virtual  Department Department { get; set; }
}
```